# Can't create remote GIT branch from Work tab in TFS 2015 Update 1

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

I've noticed that the context menu item to create a new branch is missing in my TFS 2015 Update 1 Web Portal. The illustration I'm looking at in the MSDN documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/backlogs/connect-work-items-to-git-dev-ops#CreateaGitbranchforseveralworkitems).

[image: MSDN documentation version]

My version, however, looks like this:

[image: My local version]

At first I thought it might be a process template issue. I notice the term 'Stories' in the MSDN illustration, which would indicate the Agile template. I'm using Scrum, so I get PBIs instead.

But I tried creating a test Agile project and I get the same result—no context menu to create a new branch. I'm a member of both the Project Administrators group and the Project Collection Administrators group.

Is this something that's changed between RTM and Update 1—and not updated in the documentation—or is something broken in my TFS installation?

Comment: This is a feature for a git repo, not TFS.... unless by TFS, you meant to say Visual Studio Team Services. Team Foundation Services, the version control platform, is totally different than git.

Comment: @TobiahZarlez: I'm using a Git repo under on-premises TFS. I tried TFVC but found it not to my liking for my desired configuration (i.e. no multiple repos allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is only available for VSTS:

> **Feature availability:** The work item form Development section is only
>   available for team projects hosted on Visual Studio Team Services,
>   configured with the new work item tracking experience, and configured
>   with Git for source control.

Comment: Oops... I just now spotted the heading on the illustration: "Visual Studio Team Services." Don't know how I missed that before. Working too hard I guess.

Comment: By the way... do you know whether the new Work Item form is coming to on-premises TFS at some point?

Comment: Thank you, I will. Thank you for the URL.